# How to update dataframe with bokeh callback?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh, bokehjs

I’m trying to recalculate the distance between two coordinates, one is given through 2 TextInput classes and the other is in a dataframe. I want to resolve this issue in order to select the data based on proximity conditions, maybe select options, but none of that can work unless the distance is dynamically updated based on the 2 TextInput inputs.

I followed the docs and samples, but for some reason the `df[‘distance’]` is not changing.

My code is below, I’m defining a function inside the callback to calculate the distance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, TextInput
import math
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import show

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=list('Xy'))

def distance(origin, destination):
   
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371  # km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +
         math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) *
         math.sin(dlon / 2) * math.sin(dlon / 2))
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    d = radius * c

    return d


cord_1, cord_2 = 30.56289,70.38185

df['distance'] = [distance((cord_1,cord_2),(df['X'][i],df['y'][i])) for i in range(0,len(df['X']))]
source=ColumnDataSource(df)



cord_x = TextInput(title="X-Coordinates")
cord_y = TextInput(title="Y-Coordinates")


TOOLTIPS = [

    ('Distance','@distance')
        ]


p = figure(title='Sample Distance',width = 800, height = 600,tooltips = TOOLTIPS)
p.circle(x='X',y='y',size = 10,source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, cord_x=cord_x, cord_y=cord_y),
                    code="""
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
                     
var data = source.data;
var distance = 0;
var A = cord_x.value;
var B = cord_y.value;
    
 //apply function
for(var i = 1; i < data['X'].length ; i++) {
    distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(A,B,data['X'][i],data['y']);
    data['distance'][i] = distance;
}
source.change.emit()

""")

source.js_on_change('data', callback)

layout = row(
    p,
    column(cord_x, cord_y),
)

show(layout)
```

Comment: Are you expecting a real Python dataframe to be updated? For bidirectional Python<-->JS synchronization, you have to run a Bokeh server application. Currently you are generating static, standalone HTML output  that has no connection to any Python process.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I prefer not to run bokeh server, and would rather to solve the issue using JS. Any pointers would be helpful. Is it possible to select the data that meet a certain distance condition; I.e all rows within 10km from the entered TextInput coordinates ?

Comment: Certainly, if you compute it manually in JS. Then it will affect the JavaScript data sources in the browser (only) and not affect anything in any python process.

Comment: Thank you @bigreddot, I tried with customJSFilter and cdsview but now nothing shows. My callback is now the customJSFilter with view added to the plot args: `var data = source.data;
var A = cord_x.value;
var B = cord_y.value;
var indices = [];
    
for(var i = 0; i < data['X'].length ; i++) {
    if(getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(A,B,data['X'][i],data['y']) <= 5 )
    {
            indices.push(true);
            } else {
                indices.push(false);
                } 
    
}
return indices;
""")

view=CDSView(source=source,filters=[callback])`

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding this right, you're looking to dynamically update `cord_x` and `cord_y` which serves as the base coordinate to calculate the distance from the points in your dataframe? And the coordinates themselves remain the same, while the distance in the tooltip changes.

Made a couple small changes: First, the `js_on_change` needs to be applied to the widget. Second, it needs to call 'value' as the first argument. And last, you were missing the `[i]` part in `data['y'][i]`. Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, TextInput
import math
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import show

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=list('Xy'))

def distance(origin, destination):
   
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371  # km

    dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = (math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) +
         math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) *
         math.sin(dlon / 2) * math.sin(dlon / 2))
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
    d = radius * c

    return d


cord_1, cord_2 = 30.56289,70.38185

df['distance'] = [distance((cord_1,cord_2),(df['X'][i],df['y'][i])) for i in range(0,len(df['X']))]
source=ColumnDataSource(df)

cord_x = TextInput(title="X-Coordinates")
cord_y = TextInput(title="Y-Coordinates")


TOOLTIPS = [

    ('Distance','@distance')
        ]


p = figure(title='Sample Distance',width = 800, height = 600,tooltips = TOOLTIPS)
p.circle(x='X',y='y',size = 10,source=source)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, cord_x=cord_x, cord_y=cord_y),
                    code="""
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
                     
var data = source.data;
var distance = 0;
var A = cord_x.value;
var B = cord_y.value;
    
 //apply function
for(var i = 1; i < data['X'].length ; i++) {
    distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(A,B,data['X'][i],data['y'][i]);
    data['distance'][i] = distance;
}
source.change.emit()

""")

cord_x.js_on_change('value', callback)
cord_y.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = row(
    p,
    column(cord_x, cord_y),
)

show(layout)
```